# Select book count while substracting from a joined table

Tags: mysql

I have the following table with all books:

[image: All books]

And another table to record borrowed books:

[image: Borrowed books]

My expected output should show the list of books with the current ammount (named `jumlah_buku`), calculated by substracting borrowed books:

[image: Expected output]

This is what I have tried:

`SELECT BUKU.KODE_BUKU AS 'KODE BUKU',BUKU.JUDUL AS 'JUDUL',BUKU.NAMA_PENGARANG AS 'NAMA PENGARANG', (BUKU.JUMLAH_BUKU) - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (select KODE_BUKU from PEMINJAMAN)) AS 'JUMLAH BUKU' FROM BUKU INNER JOIN PEMINJAMAN ON BUKU.KODE_BUKU = PEMINJAMAN.KODE_BUKU`

But it's not working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this correlated subquery:

```
SELECT BUKU.KODE_BUKU AS 'KODE BUKU',
BUKU.JUDUL AS 'JUDUL',
BUKU.NAMA_PENGARANG AS 'NAMA PENGARANG',
BUKU.JUMLAH_BUKU - (
    SELECT COUNT(KODE_BUKU)
    FROM PEMINJAMAN
    WHERE BUKU.KODE_BUKU = PEMINJAMAN.KODE_BUKU
) AS 'JUMLAH BUKU'
FROM BUKU;
```

Comment: ooo,This is very helpful.Thx